# Need to compress JPEGs in bulk inside folders and subfolders and clean up the original files

Tags: image, batch-file, jpeg, image-compression, webp

I have a main folder, filled with 30 subfolders, each of them containing 13 sub folders filled with jpeg images.

Their size is too big for uploading and distributing through links, so I need to bulk compress them, maintaining the folder structure. Is there any way to do this? Probably using a batch or whatever

Comment: If you choose a program which can do it via the Windows command line, then yes, a batch file can do it.

Comment: ImageMagick can do that but there's not much indication of what size your images are, what sort of compression you expect, what OS you are running, why you have tagged with `webp`, and so on.

Comment: Im running Windows 10, each subfolder has approximately 1000 jpegs, each file is 10mb approximately. I tagged webp because i know that webp has a better compression level than jpeg. I want to compress images to 80% approximately or as much as i can without losing too much quality so each link (it's 1 link per folder) doesnt take too much to download

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using a software called Caesium. It did what I needed without any complications.

I downloaded from this link
https://saerasoft.com/caesium

Thanks for the answers

Comment: you saved me hours of work. thanks alot for sharing this amazing software. kudos to the developers also.

Answer (score 0):

Please try windows command prompt command to compress your jpeg compressor because it also compresses JPEG in bulk inside folders and subfolders while maintaining the folder structure.

Ex.

```
for /r "your_folder_path" %i in (*.jpg) do "C:\Path\To\jpegcompressor.exe" "%i" -o "%i"
```

If you want to manually compress your images then you can use online application that supports bulk image compression. I recommend using https://jpegcompressor.com/ . It supports various image formats such as JPG, JPEG, SVG, PNG, WEBP and GIF and allows you to compress multiple images simultaneously without losing their original quality.

Comment: This answer currently uses Command Prompt, but the question tags imply a script is required. I would advise that you [Edit] your answer to make it relevant to the [[tag:batch-file]] tag.